# how to fix mat-expansion-panel auto collapse within mat-select?

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, angular-material2, mat-expansion-panel

I use mat-expansion-panel in my mat-select.
at first time I open `mat-select`, It's ok. But when I click out of `mat-select` to close `mat-select` 
and click to `mat-select` second time to reopen it, My `mat-expansion-panel` is closed and i must to double to open it but not single click to reopen  `mat-expansion-panel`.
Can you help me? Thanks !

```
<mat-select multiple [formControl]="formControl">
 <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let group of groups" [expanded]="true">
                <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                    <mat-panel-title title="{{group.name}}">
                        <mat-checkbox (click)="toggleGroupParent($event, group.name, group.selected)" [(ngModel)]="group.selected" >
                            {{group.name}}
                        </mat-checkbox>
                    </mat-panel-title>
                </mat-expansion-panel-header>
                <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
                    <mat-option *ngIf="item.type == group.name" [value]="item" (click)="togglePerOneInType(group.name)" title="{{item.text}}">
                        {{item.text}}
                    </mat-option>
                </ng-container>
            </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this

```
<mat-panel-title   (click)="$event.stopPropagation();">
```

Comment: If you asked friends/collegues to vote for your post, please don't